# Angular 6 display none as initial and make animation overwrite the state

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Trying to make a "custom" error tooltip.

At first state the tooltip has `.errorTooltipUnload` class:

```
.errorTooltipUnload {
    animation: tooltipUnload 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    display: none;
}
```

Uses this animation:

```
@keyframes tooltipUnload {
    0% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

And then when `hasError` is `true` it changes the class to `.errorTooltipLoad` which does the same, but the opposite of unload.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'errorTooltipLoad': hasError, 'errorTooltipUnload': !hasError}" id="loadError"></div>
```

**The problem**

When `hasError` turns false, the div just disappears without animation - Thats because it has `display: none` property by default.

If I remove this property, I will see the tooltip appear and disappear on page load.

Is there a work around that, to make the `display: none` not affect, after the animation ends?

Comment: display is not an animatable css property. if you are using angular anyway, you should use the built in animations concept instead. it is js based and therefore more powerful than pure css. you can work with void <=> * transitions there to make stuff like this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: none;` from `errorTooltipUnload`

```css
.errorTooltipUnload {
    animation: tooltipUnload 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}


@keyframes tooltipUnload {
    0% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="errorTooltipUnload" id="loadError">hello</div>
```

Comment: Yes but then it appears on page load, and then dsiappears by animation. I want it to not display at page load

Comment: do you use `form` or some `button` ?

Comment: @BenBeri Then set `opacity` to 0 by default

Comment: it will be easy to help you if you put your code in blitz frok it and post the link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6